# Error: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony

What could be the problem that some of the cron functions which always connects to the database using the code below suddenly started to fail?

It seems that it can't connect to DB. Credentials are good, they didn't changed. TestConnect is a class which is called then I want to connect to my DB. I use it like this :

```
$test = new \TestConnect(true);
```

Now the class file is found and it is working as far as I understand.

```
class TestConnect
{

private $_server = 'test';
private $_username = 'test';
private $_password = 'password';
private $_database = 'database';
private $_query = null;
private $_handle = null;
private $_handle_db = null;
private $_result = null;

public function __construct($connect = null, $query = null)
{
    if ($connect)
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    if ($query)
    {
        $this->query($query);
    }
}

public function connect()
{
    ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
    putenv("FREETDSCONF=/etc/freetds.conf");

    if ($this->_handle)
    {
        return $this->_handle;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! $this->_handle = mssql_connect($this->_server, $this->_username, $this->_password))
        {
            throw new Exception($this->get_error_message());
        }

        if ( ! $this->_handle_db = mssql_select_db($this->_database, $this->_handle))
        {
            throw new Exception($this->get_error_message());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now the most interesting thing is that if I put the $test = new \TestConnect(true); into some kind of function and call it from another function, it seems to work. But if I call to $test = new \TestConnect(true); from the very same function - it's not working.

It's working like this:

```
private function getDatabase(){
    $test = new \TestConnect(true);
    $test->query("SELECT id as id FROM table");
    return $test->fetch_assoc($trim = true);
}
```

And I call this function like:

```
$users = self::getDatabase();
```

This way the connection works and I get all the data. But if I use the code without any functions - it's not working. How is this possible?

Comment: did you upgrade to PHP7 recently?

Comment: no, version is 5.4.

Comment: Post updated with more info.

Comment: Why use `mssql_connect` when you are also using Symfony2? That seems odd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the disconnect function was causing the problems. Changed the code to disconnect from the database only once, after all the functions and data queries.